# Apache HttpClient for RestTemplate default behaviour if not setting up SSLSocketFactory and SSLContext

Tags: spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Spring RestTemplate (config using HttpClient) to make a restful service call for a URL with https.

I explicitly setup SSL using following code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial().setProtocol().build
return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext)
```

It works without any problem.

What would be the default behaviour if I don't setup SSLSocketFactory and SSLContext for HttpClient? Will it look for the cacerts under the installed JDK or it will disable the ssl?

Answer (score 1):

I say **Yes** If your https website can be passed by your browser, or your certificate file is coming from the Certificate Authority such as GlobalSign, Verisign

[image]

we can see the SSLContext and SSLSocketFactory will be created automatically, so you can visit https without doing anything

if your certificate file is not trusted, and import to jdk cacerts still can't solve this, because HttpClient download the certificate file via SSLSocket, not from the jdk cacerts

[image: verify]

Comment: If the https certificate is an internal issuing and can't be trusted by jdk's cacerts, can I import that cert to jdk's cacerts and i don't need to config SSLContext and SSLSocketFactory?

Comment: Just want to double check can I leave the HttpClient's default behaviour without configuring SSLContext if let jdk's cacerts trust the certs.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. After I imported my company's internal root ca to jdk's cacerts, it can successfully connecting to https site just with default SSLContext.

Comment: If I used original cacerts, I got exception: ```PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target```